# How to take full height screen with react and css?

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I am simply trying to make a div that is taking the full height of the screen , 
here is my code

```
import styles from './styles/Login.module.css'

class Login extends Component {
    render() {

        const onClick = () => {
          console.log("ONCLICK LOGIN");

        };

       return (
            <div className={styles.root}>
                <h1>Login</h1>
                <a href="/auth/google" onClick={onClick}>Login With Google</a>
             </div>
          );
     }
 }

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
    fetchUser: () => dispatch(fetchUser())
});
export default connect(null,mapDispatchToProps)(Login);
```

and here is my Login.module.css

```
html, body {
height: 100%;
}

.root {
    height: 100%;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

And here is the render 
[image: Render]

Comment: Try: height: 100vh

Comment: Or try, min-height: 100%

Comment: Try height: 100vh